# Iterate over urls in css file and replace text using python

Tags: python, regex

So I've been working on this for days now, but can't seem to wrap my head around the answer. Basically im trying to iterate over a css file and append to all urls within the file. So for example, `url('/css/main.css')` would be replaced with `url('/user/css/main.css)`. And this should be applicable to all url or paths irrespective of quotation marks.

With `file.replace()` I find that I replace *all* instances of that string even if it occurs multiple times leading to double replacements. So what I tried to do is remove all duplicates from the list in the beginning.

```
                        if file.endswith(".css"):
                            css = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r+')
                            urls = re.findall(r'url\((.*?)\)', css.read())
                            css.seek(0)
                            filez = str(css.read())
                            urls = [i.replace('"', '').replace('\'', '') for i in urls]
                            urlz = list(dict.fromkeys(urls))
                            for url in urlz:
                                if url[0] == '/':
                                    url = '' + url[1:]
                                    url2 = "/user/" + url
                                    filez = filez.replace(url, url2)
                                else:
                                    url = url
                            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'wb') as file:
                                file.write(filez.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

printing the list of urls (urlz) gives

```
['/fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.ttf', 
'/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf', 'Inter-Black.ttf', 
'/fonts/Inter-ExtraLight.ttf']
```

The above list is fine but how can I let the code distinguish between `'Inter-Black.ttf'` and `'/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf'`? As of now the code iterates over both replacing twice.

My Output:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Goth';
    src: url('/user/fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('/user/fonts//user/Inter-Black.ttf');
    
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url(/user/Inter-Black.ttf);
    
}
```

My Desired Output:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Goth';
    src: url('/user/fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('/user/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf');
    
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url(/user/Inter-Black.ttf);
    
}
```

How would I iterate over the list of urls in a file and append to it, without using the `replace()` method? I feel that the `replace` method is not working out for me because of the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

if I clearly understood the problem is regex and seperate '/' slashes and quotes '"'. If you divide your pattern to groups to separate problematic characters, you can build from groups new string and include there what you want.
Try something like this:

```
if file.endswith(".css"):
css = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r+').read()
t1 = re.sub(r'\(('?(.*/)?)(.*\..*)'?\)', r'\(\2/user/\4/\5\)', css)
with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'wb') as file:
    file.write(t1.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

and there you can see what group (\2, \4, \5) I used during build new string:
[pytex page with your css sample and my regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C(((%27%3F)(%2F(.*)%2F)%3F)(.*%5C..*)%27%3F%5C)&test_string=%20%40font-face%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20%27Goth%27%3B%0A%20%20%20%20src%3A%20url(%27%2Ffonts%2FLeagueGothic-Regular.ttf%27)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%40font-face%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20%27Inter%27%3B%0A%20%20%20%20src%3A%20url(%27%2Ffonts%2Fuser%2FInter-Black.ttf%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%40font-face%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20%27Inter%27%3B%0A%20%20%20%20src%3A%20url(Inter-Black.ttf)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)